# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text' when to extract value by name from HTML

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Here is my HTML, which is part of the response body from one of my API call, and from which I want to extract the `SAMLResponse` value.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
    <noscript>
      <p>
        <strong>Note:</strong>
        Since your browser does not support JavaScript,
        you must press the Continue button once to proceed.
      </p>
    </noscript>
    <form action="https://idpftc.fortinet.com/saml/Gy736KPK3v1aWDPECRZKAn/logout/" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="SAMLRequest" value="GV4Pjwvc2FtbHA6TG9nb3V0UmVxdWVzdD4K"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="RelayState" value="id-1jrGp3Fx271D7u3st|1709777499|c6ec46798457a5bb990b5c8e8a90bf34c6b55156"/>
      <noscript>
        <input type="submit" value="Continue"/>
      </noscript>
    </form>
  </body>
```

And here is my python code to try to do the extraction.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getSamlResponse(resp):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
    return soup.find('input',attrs = {'name': 'SAMLRequest'})['value']

resp = '<html code here>'
print(getSamlResponse(resp))
```

But I got such error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in getSamlResponse
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Any ideas what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

Since the variable `resp` is already a string, using the `.text` attribute on `resp` is unnecessary. Omitting the `.text` attribute will remove the AttributeError.

Answer (score 0):

If you would call your function based on following scenario it would work, because you could use `.text` on the `resp`:

```
resp = requests.get('YOUR URL')
```

If `resp` is still a string like:

```
resp = requests.get('YOUR URL').text
```

or

```
resp = '<some HTML>'
```

you have to remove `.text` because `'str' object has no attribute 'text'`:

```
def getSamlResponse(resp):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, 'lxml')
    return soup.find('input',attrs = {'name': 'SAMLResponse'})['value']
```